# Weird Keyboard Behaviour In Android Ionic App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been dealing with this particular issue for 4 days and it is really frustrating. I have a page that has a couple of form fields. When one of the input field loses focus, the keyboard slides down as expected but then a white background is displayed in place of where the keyboard appeared. I have attached an image to demonstrate the problem. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHsBB.gif
I am testing on a HTC One M8 running Android 4.4 using Ionic 1.0.0 and the Ionic Keyboard plugin. I really need help with this issue.

Comment: It appears that your screenshot is not working. Also, a model of phone and size of screen might be helpful.

Comment: @JimTheDev Yes, I just saw that. Thank you. I have edited my post.